How to configure Cloudflare with Linode NodeBalancer?
I am just new on using node balancers. Currently, my setup is like this. I have only one node (planning to add 2 or 3 more), in my node balancer. And on cloudflare I pointed the A and AAAA records to my node balancer's public IP address both v4 and v6.
My node balancer is configured this way.

Port: 80
Protocol: HTTP
Algorithm: Round Robin
Session Stickiness: HTTP Cookie

The domain in cloudflare is already fully propagated, but accessing the domain on browser, it gives me a "Web Server Down" error.
Please help. Thanks!
